# I want to join two objects but subtract the parts that will overlap

Tags: modeling

I have a hollowed out irregular bowl shape with a specific thickness that I want to stick a rectangular solid handle on the base. Ideally it would completely surround the end of the bowl shape but I want to maintain the inside hollowed out form of the bowl.

When I try to push the shapes together, the solid filled handle overlaps and fills inside the bowl it is joined to. I was wondering if there was a way to maintain 100% integrity of the bowl whilst freely adding the solid surrounding handle?

Comment: an image with what you want you have would be very helpful

Comment: thanks ok ill upload

Comment: ![here](https://ibb.co/PtM5jqv)

Comment: I think its Boolean difference maybe? Im looking for videos right now on YouTube

Comment: i still don't get it....or do you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPYEr.png ...yeah, it is a sphere, not irregular...but that way?

Comment: ![this is what is left after I hide the main body](https://ibb.co/R7WKx8r) but I want that inside removed not maintained. Maybe I will have to make the main bowl solid first, do the boolean difference and then hollow the bowl again afterwards?

Comment: yeah that way but my shape is a bit more complicated as it has a slit down side so the boolean method is just subtracting the part that is in physical contact

Comment: I want the rectangular surround but maintain the hollow centre inside if that makes sense

Comment: i know you meant irregular...so like this, right? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sosYO.png

Comment: Yes, did you see the picture https://ibb.co/PtM5jqv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is: duplicate your irregular part. Then close the top face.

Use this as boolean modifier object and just hide it in render and viewport display.

example:

[image]

duplicate that object and close it:

[image]

move it to the box

[image]

give the box a boolean modifier with the closed object:

[image]

set visibility of closed object:

[image]

result:
[image]

put back your original object:

[image]

Hint: "normally" you wouldn't move the original and the cutter object, i just did it here that you can see which object is which.

Comment: That's amazing thanks so much I will give it a go :)